# iptables forward non-local traffic through ssh proxy

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, proxy, iptables

I trying to forward traffic from a local port to a remote machine through SSH **proxy** (not tunnel).
I learned, that it can't be done only with iptables rules (please correct me, if it's not true), so I set up REDSOCKS to redirect TCP connections to the SSH SOCKS proxy.
I managed to transport the local traffic to the remote machine with iptables rules in the OUTPUT chain, but the same concept in the PREROUTING not working.
The goal is to make the local machine view the outside internet as it would be in the remote machine's network (like a VPN).

```
----------                      --------------
| inside |  <-- 10.0.0.0/24 --> |-> iptables |
----------                      |      |     |
                                |      ˇ     |
                                |   redsocks |
                                |      |     |
                                |      ˇ     |                  ----------
                                |     ssh -> | <-- internet --> | remote |
                                --------------                  ----------
```

Note: I don't want to do anything (changing configuration, adding routes) on the remote machine!

SSH connection established with `ssh -D 1337 user@remote`.
Redsocks is already configured and started, listening on port `12345`.

on the middles machine:

```bsh
OUTSIDE_INTERFACE=wlan0
INSIDE_INTERFACE=eth0
SSH_SOCKS_PORT=1337
REDSOCKS_PORT=12345

# set the ip address
ifconfig $INSIDE_INTERFACE 10.0.0.1 netmask 255.255.255.0

# enable ip forwarding
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward

# reset iptables
iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -F
iptables -F
iptables -X

# redirect local traffic, except traffic from redsocks to ssh
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport $SSH_SOCKS_PORT -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp -j REDIRECT --to-ports $REDSOCKS_PORT

# redirect traffic from inside
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -j REDIRECT --to-ports $REDSOCKS_PORT
```

So after this, traffic from the local machine get redirected, and I see the internet as I would be in the remote network!
But the inside machine **cannot** access to the internet.

(The ip address on the *inside* machine already set, tested with a successful ping.)

I tried:

- `iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -s 10.0.0.0/24 -p tcp -j REDIRECT --to-ports 12345`
- adding `iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o $OUTSIDE_INTERFACE -j MASQUERADE`

If I **only** set the `iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o $OUTSIDE_INTERFACE -j MASQUERADE` rule **alone**, the inside machine can access to the internet (but not through the proxy).

After trying to connect, I see the following statistics:

```
# iptables -t nat -nvL
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 10 packets, 641 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
   42  2184 REDIRECT   tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            redir ports 12345

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 43 packets, 2244 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 19 packets, 1164 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
   18  1080 RETURN     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:1337
   18  1080 REDIRECT   tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            redir ports 12345

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 46 packets, 2825 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

As I understand, it means that the packets from the inside machine also get redirected, but than lost somewhere...

Also I have some question

- why the ssh traffic not get redirected by the `iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp -j REDIRECT --to-ports $REDSOCKS_PORT` rule? I only filtered the `$SSH_SOCKS_PORT` port...

[iptables flowchart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1qq7q.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, the problem was not with the iptables rules, or not mainly.
Iptables REDIRECT [do the following:](https://linux.die.net/man/8/iptables)

> It redirects the packet to the machine itself by changing the destination IP to the primary **address of the incoming interface** (locally-generated packets are mapped to the 127.0.0.1 address).

And redsocks, by default, listen only to packet came to **127.0.0.1**, so packets with the destination of an interface address won't arrive to redsocks.

After changing redsocks config to **`local_ip = 0.0.0.0;`** it worked.

(Note: it's only for TCP, for UDP (like DNS) further settings needed.)

Comment: Please have a look at [Can I answer my own question?](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer) and come back two days later and check as answered if you have more than 15 reputation.

Answer (score 0):

According to your situation, you only need to monitor redsocks to 10.0.0.1, then REDIRECT or DNAT, for example

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --syn -j DNAT --to 10.0.0.1:12345
```

I encountered the same problem as you. I was confused by OUTPUT and kept listening on 127.0.0.1.

Reference: [Routing a VPN connection to a socks proxy on the same server](https://superuser.com/q/1347117/214658)